# File is not downloading from server

Tags: java, struts2

I want to download a pdf file from the server. I am using tomcat. and developing the application in struts2.

In my JSP code the link for download is as below:

```
<td>
    <a href='<s:url action='downloadPdf'> </s:url>'>
        Download PDF</a>
</td>
```

My struts.xml is:

```
<action name="downloadPdf" class="com.stp.portal.view.SearchServicePortlet" method="downloadPdf">
</action>
```

Action class is:

```
    public void downloadPdf() throws Exception
    {
        HttpServletResponse response = null;
        try
        {
            response.setContentType ("application/pdf");
            File f = new File ("D:\\abc.pdf");
            response.setHeader ("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=abc.pdf");
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
            ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
            int bit = 256;
            int i = 0;
            try 
            {
                while ((bit) >= 0) 
                {
                    bit = inputStream.read();
                    servletOutputStream.write(bit);
                }
                }
                catch (Exception ioe) 
                {
                    ioe.printStackTrace(System.out);
                }
                servletOutputStream.flush();
                inputStream.close();    
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
                    
        }
    }
    
    public String generateGraph() throws Exception
    {
        return "success";
    }
}
```

My problem is when i click on the download link the file is not downloaded. abc.pdf file is inside the local disk D. Dont know what is wrong. Would really appreciate if someone could help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Can you verify the file is being read from disk and indeed sent back to the response?

Comment: Besides, it might be interesting to work with a `byte[]` instead of reading / writing one byte at a time, in order to increase performance.

Comment: You should close your input stream in a finally block. If there is an I/O error for one reason or another and close() is not reached, you leak the file descriptor

Comment: i have tried debugging, but nothing is there, no error

Comment: Are you using Java 7 or Java 6?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ERROR: application/pdf is not a supported mime type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721094/error-application-pdf-is-not-a-supported-mime-type)

Answer (score 0):

try changing your code to something like this:

```
response.setContentType("application/force-download");
File f = new File ("D:\\abc.pdf");
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"abc.pdf\"");
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
BufferedOutputStream out =
                new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
byte by[] = new byte[32768];
int index;
if (inputStream != null) {
    index = inputStream.read(by, 0, 32768);
} else {
    index = -1;
}
while (index != -1) {
    out.write(by, 0, index);
    index = inputStream.read(by, 0, 32768);
}
out.flush();
```

Comment: thanks MaVRoSCy for your reply, but its working for me, 
response.setContentType("application/force-download");
 is getting errored in the console.

Comment: what do you mean `getting errored` Any exception? That line shouldn't cause any problems

Comment: [Never use that hack :@](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10616753/1654265)... `Content-Disposition: attachment` is enough to ensure the file is asked for download, or threated in the way the browser's settings are configured by the user (always open, always download etc)

Comment: @user2594235 did you try my code using `response.setContentType ("application/pdf");` instead of `response.setContentType("application/force-download");` ?

Answer (score 0):

Change to this code. Note the handling of the input stream: it is correctly closed in the event of an I/O error:

```
final byte[] buf = new byte[16384];
int count;

final InputStream in = new FileInputStream(...);
final OutputStream out = servlet.getOutputStream();

try {
    while ((count = in.read(buf)) != -1)
        out.write(buf, 0, count);
    out.flush();
} catch (...) {
} finally {
    in.close();
}
```

If you can afford it, use Guava and its `Closer` to handle I/O resources.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [sample-struts portlet](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins/blob/master/portlets/sample-struts-portlet) for Liferay which contains a downloaded custom type that is not embedded in the full portal page - e.g. the content type can be something different than the usual portal's HTML. In [this example](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins/blob/master/portlets/sample-struts-portlet/docroot/WEB-INF/src/com/liferay/samplestruts/struts/action/ViewChartAction.java) it's image/jpeg. Apply this according to your problem.