# PDF downloading from server in struts2

Tags: java, struts2, liferay, liferay-6

I need to download a pdf file from server to the client machine on clicking a link. I am using liferay 6.1, tomacat, struts2. I am giving here the complete flow:

Jsp Page:

```
<td>
    <a href='<s:url action='download'> </s:url>'>
         Download PDF</a>
</td>
```

Struts.xml:

```
<action name="download" class="com.stp.portal.view.DownloadAction">
            <result name="success" type="stream">
                <param name="contentType">application/pdf</param>
                <param name="inputName">fileInputStream</param>
                <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="abc.pdf"</param>
                <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
            </result>
        </action>
```

DownlaodAction.java:

```
public class DownloadAction extends ActionSupport{

    private InputStream fileInputStream;

    public InputStream getFileInputStream() {
        return fileInputStream;
    }

    public String execute() throws Exception {

        if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
            try {
                File myFile = new File("D:\\abc.pdf");
                Desktop.getDesktop().open(myFile);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // no application registered for PDFs
            }
        }
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\abc.pdf"));
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

When I click the downloadPDF in the jsp, below error meassage is coming:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: application/pdf is not a supported mime type
    at com.liferay.portlet.MimeResponseImpl.setContentType(MimeResponseImpl.java:159)
```

I have tried my best to solve this, but not working for me, I have tried octet-stream, but still giving the error. Would really appreciate someone's help. If there is any other option then please give me the complete code. Basically I want to download the file abc.java from the server to the client machine.

Thanks

Comment: Don't post same question twice. And look at my answer in your previous question. http://stackoverflow.com/q/17721094/1700321

Comment: So it is actually third time: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17716458/1700321.

Comment: Show generated url for download action.