# Liferay and struts2

Tags: java, struts2, liferay

Sorry for may bad English.

I am try to download docx file within a struts2 liferay portlet.

In my portlet.xml i specify portlet-class:

```
<portlet-name>test-portlet</portlet-name>
<display-name>Test</display-name>
    <portlet-class>org.apache.struts2.portlet.dispatcher.Jsr286Dispatcher</portlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <name>viewNamespace</name>
        <value>/view</value>
    </init-param>
```

Action in struts.xml:

```
<action name="GenerateReport" class="org.test.GenerateReportAction"
        method="generateReport">
        <result name="success" type="stream">
            <param name="inputName">resultInputStream</param>
            <param name="contentType">application/msword</param>
            <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="Test_SumaryReport.docx"</param>
            <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
            <param name="contentLength"></param>
        </result>
    </action>
```

In jsp:

```
<a href='<s:url action='GenerateReport' > </s:url>'>download</a>
```

When i am try to download file i have exception:

```
10:26:59,805 ERROR [Jsr168Dispatcher:38] Could not execute action java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: application/msword is not a supported mime type
    at com.liferay.portlet.MimeResponseImpl.setContentType(MimeResponseImpl.java:159)
    at org.apache.struts2.portlet.servlet.PortletServletResponseJSR286.setContentType(PortletServletResponseJSR286.java:148)
    at org.test.GenerateReportAction.generateReport(GenerateReportAction.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:452)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:291)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:254)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:263)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:133)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:142)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:166)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:190)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.portlet.interceptor.PortletAwareInterceptor.intercept(PortletAwareInterceptor.java:82)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.portlet.interceptor.PortletStateInterceptor.intercept(PortletStateInterceptor.java:57)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    at org.apache.struts2.portlet.dispatcher.Jsr168Dispatcher.serviceAction(Jsr168Dispatcher.java:463)
    at org.apache.struts2.portlet.dispatcher.Jsr168Dispatcher.render(Jsr168Dispatcher.java:334)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:100)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:64)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:73)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:530)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:534)
```

Why liferay use Jsr168Dispatcher when  portlet class Jsr286Dispatcher?

If you know  how to resolve this problem it would be great to know it!

Thank you very much!

Comment: See my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17721094/1700321.

Comment: @AleksandrM Dear Aleksandr, thanks for your answer! If use portletUrlType="resource" in <s:url> when i try download file open new blank tab in browser and throw exceprion: 12:35:37,289 ERROR [Jsr168Dispatcher:38] Could not find action There is no Action mapped for action name GenerateReport. - [unknown location] What could be the problem?

Comment: Post complete struts.xml file and show rendered url.

Answer (score 0):

quoting my answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/17743269/13447:

There's a [sample-struts portlet](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins/blob/master/portlets/sample-struts-portlet) for Liferay which contains a downloaded custom type that is not embedded in the full portal page - e.g. the content type can be something different than the usual portal's HTML. In [this example](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins/blob/master/portlets/sample-struts-portlet/docroot/WEB-INF/src/com/liferay/samplestruts/struts/action/ViewChartAction.java) it's image/jpeg. Apply this according to your problem.

You'll have to understand that a typical "action" request to your struts action *will be* part of the resulting HTML page, e.g. it *must* be of proper HTML mimetype. If you do a resource request (like Aleksandr M suggests in his answer on [ERROR: application/pdf is not a supported mime type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17721094/1700321)) you can deliver any content type.

Jsr168Dispatcher is the [supertype of Jsr286Dispatcher](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/struts2-plugins/struts2-portlet-plugin/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/portlet/dispatcher/Jsr286Dispatcher.html). So for every method that Jsr286Dispatcher doesn't override, the stacktrace lists the class that actually implements a method.

http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/struts2-plugins/struts2-portlet-plugin/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/portlet/dispatcher/Jsr286Dispatcher.html