# Force image download with php using header() in smartphones and tablets

Tags: php, iphone, image, ipad, smartphone

I was searching already for a long time and I havent seen any right answer yet.

I'm trying to create a system in PHP where the user can download a signPicture that I create in JPG.
The program is working fine in all desktop computers. There is not problem at all, even for IE8.

The header that I use:

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.jpg"');
```

in the end i just stream the picture:

```
imagejpeg($imgSign,NULL,100);
```

How I said, it's working really good in every browser. But then we get to the mobile devices, where in android for example, download a test.jpg file... but then it cannot open... and the same with ipad (actually doesnt download, it show the image in the browser and than I save it... but it does not open either).

I also try more examples that I saw, but doesnt change anything, like:

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");
```

Any idea how to sort this out in mobile devices?

Thanks!

Comment: You save it, but it cannot be opened. What you mean by that, the file is not created? Is it created empty? Is it created but don't work? Is it smaller than it should be? Is there something weird in its content? What exactly is happening?

Comment: Regarding mobile browsers check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615797/utility-of-http-header-content-type-application-force-download-for-mobile for more details

Comment: It save the file, and i can see that is in the phone or tablet. But then when I try open to open it, its unreadeble, so it say: your picture its unreadable or, a black screen with JPG charachter in the middle... If I send the file from my phone to my computer, its also not readable, but I can see that it actually has a size (its not null).

Comment: About the Jake answer. Im not forcing the download: "application/force-download", it does download... but it just a file that it doesnt open later...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it!

There were differents problems. I found the clear solution in comments from this post:
http://www.digiblog.de/2011/04/android-and-the-download-file-headers/

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.JPG"');
```

The important steps: I send everything with a form. The form, to make it work in mobiles, needs to have the target='_top' and the method='get'

It also make errors if the extention (jpg) is not in UPPERCASE and the file name is not between " ".

Now it works in all devices that I try by far. :)

Special thanks to Jörg Wagner, author of the post.

Comment: Nice suggestion, but this doesn't work. On iOS the image is shown in the browser, but not downloaded (without the user saving it).