# How do I create and download a csv file using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, csv, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, encodeuricomponent

I have this code in a button:

```
var csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
csvContent += myCSVcontent;

var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
window.open(encodedUri);
```

This works perfectly in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.
- But not IE8 - I need Internet Explorer 8 compatibility.

When I click the button that calls the code above it downloads the .csv file to my computer.
When I click the button in IE8 though, it opens a new IE8 window with all the csv contents in the address bar and does not download (or ask to download) anything.

Unfortunately, I have to have IE8 compatibility. How can I make this work?

Edit: I must avoid any additional calls to the server.  Everything needs to happen client side.  This is currently working in all browsers except IE8 (and possibly IE9).

Edit2: When I change the last line to "document.location.href= encodedUri;" it will still work on all other browsers but in IE8 when I click the button I get an error window that says "The data area passed to a system call is too small."  Any idea what that is telling me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Utility of HTTP header "Content-Type: application/force-download" for mobile?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615797/utility-of-http-header-content-type-application-force-download-for-mobile)

Comment: In Chrome this is blocked as a pop-up (at least in v35 it is).

Answer (score 0):

"data:text/csv;" is HTML5 so it will not work for IE8, i'm able to solve this using ActivexObject, but it's writing the file to user's desktop and no popup

```
var csv = new ActiveXObject("scripting.FileSystemObject");
var fLoc = csv.CreateTextFile(fileName);
fLoc.WriteLine(csvData);
fLoc.close();
```