# Why am I getting this error in IE: "The data area passed to a system call is too small"?

Tags: javascript, excel, csv, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I'm creating a csv file for download using Javascript and it's working perfectly fine in everything except for IE (I've tested 8 and 10).

In IE8, when I click the button to create and download the file I get an error that comes up and says `"The data area passed to a system call is too small"`.  In IE10, when I click the button it just opens a new tab that has the URL I've created in the address bar but doesn't download anything.

Any ideas what this error means?

I have this code in a button:

```
var csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
csvContent += escape(myCSVvariable);

var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
window.open(encodedUri);
```

This is related to this question but I started a new one because I got a different error after changing some things - [How do I create and download a csv file using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20843219/how-do-i-create-and-download-a-csv-file-using-javascript)

Comment: IE gives error If your content is longer than 2,000 characters

Comment: Use `navigator.msSaveBlob` to save big files, e.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16376161/javascript-set-file-in-download

Comment: IE11 still has this issue

Answer (score 25):

This is a known issue, but there is a workaround.

Add the following code

```
if (navigator.msSaveBlob) 
{ // IE 10+ 
navigator.msSaveBlob(new Blob([csv], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' }), "filename.csv"); 
}
```

and the issue should be resolved. This works for IE10, I have not tested it on IE8 (I don't have IE8 anymore!)

Refer to:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/Hh772331

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/Hh772298

[Source](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/script122-data-area-passed-system-call-too-small-ie-ravindramohan)

Comment: Nice one, this saved me some time

Comment: @Andrew glad I could help.. always good to cut down bug fixing time! :)

Answer (score 3):

There is a size restriction of URL in IE.

Comment: @nipiv: Consider to write api and then you post all the content to the server through http. From the server, write a logic to handle the data from client and export the csv file. Normally you will need to do something with the respond and Content-Disposition header. Take a look at https://goosedotnet.wordpress.com/2014/09/29/generate-and-export-a-string-only-csv-file-from-webapi/

Comment: Well we already had a solution where the backend wud create the excel, but i was looking for a for a frontend solution. i found some libraries like xlsz.js which does the trick. But we have gone back to a backend downlodable solution.