# Internet Explorer - The data area passed to a system call is too small - Downloading png with the uri

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, png, uri

I am trying to download a png file using the uri (code below). It works in Chrome, Firefox and Safari - but not (of course) in Internet Explorer. I am on Windows 7, so I am using IE11 in Edge Document Mode. The error is "The data area passed to a system call is too small." I've read  in [this MDN post](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs#Common_problems)

> IE9 and later, as well as Edge, supports data URIs in CSS and JS
>   files, but not in HTML files, with a max size of 4GB.

My URI is only 1410 bytes (using uri.length). Any ideas why I am getting the error with data of this size and how to fix it?

The download function:

```
function downloadURI(uri, name) {
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = name;
    link.href = uri;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
    delete link;
}
```

The uri format:

```
"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgo ETC..."
```

Comment: `delete link;` -> [`delete operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete): _"Any property declared with var cannot be deleted from the global scope or from a function's scope."_

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20844644/why-am-i-getting-this-error-in-ie

Comment: @Andreas - I tried =>  `if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { return navigator.msSaveBlob(new Blob([uri], {type: "image/png"}), name);}`
It downloaded fine, but the file could not be read as a PNG. Suggestions?

Comment: No, just found the link and it looked promising :|

Comment: Try pasting `data:text/html,Hello folks` into the address bar - it worked in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE. Same result for a short, valid data URI for a PNG image. _IE appears unable to navigate to a data URI_.

Comment: @Andreas - Thanks for your link. It gave me what I needed to search on and so found an answer, which I posted below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is below. I can't seem to find the link to give credit, but this solved it. Instead of converting the canvas to a uri first, I pass the canvas and either convert to a uri and download using a link or (for IE) I convert to a blob and use canavas.msToBlob() and msSaveBlob()

```
function downloadURI(canvas, name) {
  if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE10+
    var blob = canvas.msToBlob();
    return navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, name);
  } else {
    var uri = canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = name;
    link.href = uri;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    if (link.click) {
      link.click();
    } else {
      var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
      event.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window);
      link.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
    document.body.removeChild(link);
  }
}
```