# How to fix CRLF injection flaws for the below code

Tags: vb.net, veracode, crlf-vulnerability

I have a VB.NET application which had a security scan and two CRLF injection flaws were identified. Can someone please help me to fix the flaw? The code is as below

1. In a code behind .vb file

   ```
   Dim strFileName As String = Path.GetFileName(FName).Replace(" ", "%20")
   Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream" ' FLaw identified in this line
   Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", ("attachment; filename=" + strFileName)) ' 
   Response.Clear()
   Response.WriteFile(FName)
   Response.End()
   ```
2. In a aspx page

   ```
   <%   
       Response.Clear()
       Response.ContentType = "application/force-download"
       Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=""" & 
       Request.QueryString("filename") & """")  ' flaw identified at this line           
       Response.Buffer = True
       Response.Flush()
       Response.WriteFile(Request.QueryString("path"))
       Response.End()
   %>
   ```

Comment: a) You wouldn't need to replace the strings in 1. if you used quotes around the filename like you do in 2. b) Veracode might be confused. c) The string concatenation operator in VB is `&`, not `+`. d) You should not be using aspx pages for file downloads - a generic handler (.ashx) works better. e) In 2., are you really intending to allow hackers to download any file that your web site has file access to? f) Using Response.End like that will stop some browsers from being able to download the file.

Comment: ... and g) [Utility of HTTP header “Content-Type: application/force-download” for mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10616753/1115360).

Comment: Hi Andrew, Many thanks for your reply. The below code should do?


Dim strFileName As String = Server.UrlEncode(Path.GetFileName(FName))
                Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", ("attachment; filename=" & strFileName))
                Response.Clear()
                Response.WriteFile(FName)
                Response.End()